# Задание по C++, структуры и функции

Tags: c++

Прошу помочь с программой: у нас есть 4 магазина a, b, c и d. 
Каждый имеет свою цену на товар и свою дистанцию от дома.
Нужно чтобы программа как бы пробежалась по всем четырем структурам и вывела на экран названия тех магазинов, в которых цена товара менее 30 и расстояние менее 400.

Укажите пожалуйста на ошибки

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Shop {
    int price;
    int distantion;
    char name;
};

char Funct (int price, int distantion, char name) {
    for Shop
    {
        if (price < 30, distantion < 400)
        cout << "Podhohyashie magaziny - " << name <<endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char a, b, c, d;
        int price;
        char name;

        Shop first;
        first.price = 20;
        first.distantion = 200;
        first.name = a ;

        Shop second;
        second.price = 25;
        second.distantion = 300;
        second.name = b ;

        Shop third;
        third.price = 32;
        third.distantion = 420
        third.name = c;

        Shop fourth;
        fourth.price = 35;
        fourth.distantion = 500;
        fourth.name = d;

        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: а должны быть ошибки?

Comment: да, я в этом новичок, а точнее дилетантка)

Answer (score 2):

У меня к вам личная просьба: разберитесь основательно в приведенном коде, и сами найдите все свои ошибки (их я насчитал... ну, пальцев одной руки точно не хватило :)). Это уже не дилетантизм, это полное незнание языка.

Если вы не намерены разбираться, а просто хотите сдать - пожалуйста, не смотрите на приведенный код...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Shop {
    int price;
    int distantion;
    char name;
} shops[] = {
    {20,200,'a'},
    {25,300,'b'},
    {32,420,'c'},
    {35,500,'d'}
};

int main()
{

    for (auto shop: shops)
        if (shop.price < 30 && shop.distantion < 400)
            cout << "Podhohyashie magaziny - " << shop.name << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: развелись тут    критики, умеющие только голосовать против...

Answer (score 0):

Положить бы эти структуры в вектор  `std::vector<Shop> shops` , и пробегая по вектору `for (auto& i : shops)`, при `i.price < 30 && i.destination < 400` выводить `std::cout << i.name << std::endl;`